# Existence of a matrix satisfying a given equation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose I looked at the equation in $Z^n=1$. Now to construct a matrix which satisfies this equation may seem simple if I just put the roots of the above equation in the diagonal like this:  $$
        \begin{pmatrix}
     1 & 0& 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
     0 & \omega_1& 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
     \vdots  & \vdots& \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
     0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & \omega_{n-1}    
     \end{pmatrix}
$$

where $\{1,\omega_1,\omega_2,...,\omega_{n-1}\}$, are the $n$ roots of unity. 
Now the problem arises if the question is slightly changed to a real matrix (except $I_n$). Will there be a real matrix except ($I_n$) which will satisfy this equation??

More generally: Given an equation what guarantees that a matrix will exist which will satisfy the given equation?? Will there always be such a matrix??

Comment: Could you perhaps clarify your last couple questions?

Answer (score 2):

Consider any real polynomial $P(X)=X^n-a_{n-1}X^{n-1}-\cdots-a_1X-a_0$, than
the matrix $$
A=\left[\matrix{0&0&\cdots&0&a_0\cr
1&0&\cdots&0&a_1\cr
0&1&\cdots&0&a_2\cr
\vdots& & & &\vdots\cr
0&0&\cdots&1&a_{n-1}\cr
}\right]
$$
Satisfies $P(A)=0$. This is called the [Companion Matrix](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CompanionMatrix.html).

Answer (score 0):

There are many examples of such matrices, but one class that springs to mind is cyclic permutation matrices: any $n\times n$ cyclic permutation matrix raised to the $n$-th power gives you back the identity (because it's the equivalent of applying the permutation $n$ times which gives you back the identity permutation).

Answer (score 0):

Consider the real $n\times n$ matrix $A$ defined by
$$a_{i,j}=\cases{1&if $i=j+1$\cr 1&if $i=1$, $j=n$\cr 0&otherwise.\cr}$$
Then $A^n=I$.

**Proof**.  This is the [companion matrix](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CompanionMatrix.html) of the polynomial $z^n-1$.  It therefore has $n$ distinct eigenvalues, namely, the $n$th roots of $1$, so it is similar to a diagonal matrix $D$ with these roots on the diagonal.  So $A^n=PD^nP^{-1}=PIP^{-1}=I$.

**Comment**.  This is also a permutation matrix and is therefore a special case of Peter Woolfitt's answer.